# How to check the type of typed class <?>

Tags: java, reflection

I am passing the parameter in the method which has declared to be accepted parameter `type class<?>` ...other, after passing the parameter like `String.class` and `Integer.class` I want to know the type (class of) parameter which has been passed in this methods.

What parameter I received, I converted it into object and tring to checking the type but it is not working.

```
public void processVarargIntegers(String label, Class<?>... others) {

    System.out.println(String.format("processing %s arguments for %s", others.length, label));
    Arrays.asList(others).forEach(a -> {

        try {
            Object o = a;
            if (o instanceof Integer) {
                System.out.println(" >>>>>>>>>>>>> Integer");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

```
public void processVarargIntegers(String label, Class<?>... others) {

    System.out.println(String.format("processing %s arguments for %s", others.length, label));
    Arrays.asList(others).forEach(a -> {

        try {
            Object o = a;
            if (o instanceof Integer) {
                System.out.println(" Integer");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

if a is the instance of the integer `System.out.println(" Integer");` should be executed

Comment: `Class<?>` will always be classes not objects. So `o instanceof ...` would only be true when checked for  `Class`. What you want is something like `Integer.class.isAssignableFrom(o)` to check whether you've got `Integer.class` or a subclass (to get the exact class just use `Integer.class.equals(o)`).

Comment: Btw, why did you post the exact same method (except for the print statement) twice? Also note that `Object o = a;` isn't necessary at all. Finally note that the name `processVarargIntegers` indicates that `others` should contain _values_ and not classes, so the type of `others` might have to be `Object` (or, if you only want to allow numbers, a more specific common supertype like `Number`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check the class you could use `if (a == Integer.class )`

```
public void processVarargIntegers(String label, Class<?>... others) {
    System.out.println(String.format("processing %s arguments for %s", others.length, label));
    Arrays.asList(others).forEach(a -> {
        try {
            if (a == Integer.class) {
                System.out.println(" >>>>>>>>>>>>> Integer");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That if statement will never work since you objects are instances of `Class<?>`. This will work:

```
if (o == Integer.class)
    System.out.println("Integer")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print out the name of the classes, this would be a simple solution to go:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main().processVarargIntegers("test", Integer.class, String.class, Number.class);
  }

  public void processVarargIntegers(String label, Class<?>... others) {
    System.out.println(String.format("processing %s arguments for %s", others.length, label));
    Arrays.asList(others).forEach(a -> System.out.println(a.getName()));
  }
}
```

output would be then:

```
processing 3 arguments for test
java.lang.Integer
java.lang.String
java.lang.Number
```